# JQUERY 1.4.4 script error - "Object required" - when executing a load in IE 8 but not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, load

I'm a newcomer in the field of JQUERY, but I quickly became addicted.  I'm now playing around with the load function a lot, and maybe a bit too much.  I'm currently developing a site, which works great in FF, Chrome and Safari, but as you can guess, I have issues with IE8 ( haven't tested it on other versions yet).

You can view it here:
http://dev.denisduvauchelle.com/blp/b2b/index.php

It all works fine until I load a catalogue or collection page.  At that point, nothing loads and IE8 informs me of this:
Object required
jquery144min.js  -> line 108 -> Char: 464 -> Code 0
and nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should load the non-minified version of jQuery 1.4.4 and run the program with that.  That will let you see what's going on in the jQuery code more easily. It seems that it's having problems with the result of the `$.load()` call, and for me it only fails when IE8 is in "IE7" mode.

Comment: (Actually I'm having problems in 1.8 mode too, and it's annoying because something about this is crashing the whole browser, at least when I run with the debugger.)

Comment: I did what you said, and I now I get an error on line 5137 at this section.   for ( var j = tbody.length - 1; j >= 0 ; --j ) { if ( jQuery.nodeName( tbody[ j ], "tbody" ) && !tbody[ j ].childNodes.length ) { tbody[ j ].parentNode.removeChild( tbody[ j ] ); } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the unminified jQuery 1.4.4. It's far easier to debug when the code isn't smooshed onto one line.

---

**Update:** You have some dirty HTML that may be mucking things up. Find all occurrences of < and > that *aren't* part of HTML tags (ie. "CATALOGUE > Cufflinks") and replace then with their HTML entity equivalents:

- `>` = `&gt;`
- `<` = `&lt;`

Comment: Ok, so I put the unminified version.  Now the error is on line 5137, Char: 12.

Comment: Which is this: for ( var j = tbody.length - 1; j >= 0 ; --j ) {
      if ( jQuery.nodeName( tbody[ j ], "tbody" ) && !tbody[ j ].childNodes.length ) {
       tbody[ j ].parentNode.removeChild( tbody[ j ] );
      }
     }